# Allow changing votes on answers if the question is edited

Tags: feature-request, voting, edits

Recently I downvoted the answer because I thought it didn't answer the question.  Not very uncommon reason to downvote, isn't it?  But then the guy, who asked the question, edited his question and I realized that the answer I downvoted actually answers it and deserves an upvote instead!  But I couldn't do it.

I could do it if the answerer had edited his post.   As I understand, the rationale of changing vote after edit is the following.  If I came to the question page for the first time *after* the edit of *the answer*, I would've upvoted it instead of downvoting.

But why doesn't the same rationale hold for the cases when the *question* is edited?  Unless there's a good reason, I suggest to allow changing answer vote on *question* edits, not only on *answer* ones.

Comment: We should be able to change our votes no matter what.  It shouldn't require anything to be edited or changed.

Comment: +1 to @endolith comment. It's our vote, we should be able to change it. At least during the first minutes...

Comment: I came here to post this same request. Many times the OP adds clarification that makes previously incorrect answers correct, or vice versa. I suppose another "solution" is to ask users to wait until all clarifications are addressed before casting votes, but that's not very realistic, and sometimes not even possible.

Comment: All of these questions are old, but possible duplicates: [Be able to edit a vote on an answer if the question is changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32266/be-able-to-edit-a-vote-on-an-answer-if-the-question-is-changed), [Vote change on ANSWER if QUESTION is edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34437/vote-change-on-answer-if-question-is-edited) (I'm not sure which should be closed as duplicates of which)

Answer (score 10):

+1 for this request. As an interim, assuming you don't have enough rep to edit, you can comment on the answer you DV'ed, explaining that you'd like to reverse your vote, and request that the answerer edit his post in a minor way so you can. I don't like this solution, though -- I much prefer your feature request.

If you have enough rep to edit, go with RSolberg's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd also like to support this request and point out that it's a silly restriction anyways, as anybody with >= 2k rep can change their vote whenever they want simply by trivially editing the answer they want to change their vote on (e.g. shuffling some whitespace around).

At the bare minimum, just make it so anybody with >= 2k rep can change their votes at any time - if you're going to allow this anyways you might as well reduce arbitrary edits by just letting votes change.

Since there's an easy way around the voting thing, either figure out a way to prevent the workaround, or just drop the rule. Anyways I'm not sure I understand the rationale behind preventing vote changes in the first place. Perhaps stopping vote changes a few *weeks* after a vote is cast is more aligned with whatever the goal is there.

Comment: I agree.  I had an instance today with such a situation.  Good question.  Bad answer.  Bad answer downvoted. Bad answer edited.  Now a good answer can't be upvoted.