# Allow changing votes on answer if question has been edited

Tags: feature-request, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Be able to edit a vote on an answer if the question is changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32266/be-able-to-edit-a-vote-on-an-answer-if-the-question-is-changed)

Scenario:

1. User1 posts a question
2. User2 posts an answer to said question
3. I vote on User2's answer because it appears to solve the problem
4. Several days later, User1 edits his question. The changes aren't dramatic, but it invalidates User2's answer
5. I want to change my vote on User2's answer, because it no longer answers the question. However, I cannot, because User2 has not edited his answer

Questions, of course, can be voted on based on their content. Answers, however, don't exist in a vacuum. A good answer can very easily become a bad answer (or *vice versa*) if the nature of the question it is answering changes.

So...

Please reset the votelock on answers if the question is edited.