# Allow me to change my vote if I discover an answer is wrong after I upvote it

Tags: discussion, voting, wrong-answers

I asked a question about [Google Plus and OpenSocial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720724/google-plus-and-opensocial) on Stack Overflow. A long time passed without any answers being posted, but I finally got [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720724/google-plus-and-opensocial/6742132#6742132). I voted for it, not knowing any better. It turned out the answer was wrong, but I can't remove my vote, since the answer hasn't been edited.

There should be a process for removing your vote when you realize an answer is wrong after you upvote it.

Comment: but is such a behavior (edit just to re-vote) wanted in SO?

Comment: A similar scenario was discussed at [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32266/be-able-to-edit-a-vote-on-an-answer-if-the-question-is-changed/32304#comment-267282). @Carlos, quack suggested doing just that, but it was two years ago not an identical situation.

Comment: @Traroth: To clarify my previous comment: If you can't change your vote since it is now frozen, add a comment to the answer explaining that/why it is wrong now.

Comment: How come you didn't yet comment on that answer, explaining why it's wrong? Simply removing your upvote isn't going to help a lot.

Answer (score 11):

No, there shouldn't. The lesson here is not that the system is wrong. Users shouldn't be voting on answers before they know whether those answers are correct.

Comment: So there is no place for mistakes. Too bad the system is not designed for human beings...

Comment: That's ridiculous. Yes, people will make mistakes, but that doesn't give you an excuse to not try. Don't blame the system for your incorrect actions.

Comment: @Popular Demand: I don't get your point. Most people try to avoid mistakes, and everybody does some anyway.

Comment: @Traroth Now you know not to vote before you test, that's the point.  And the occasional minor mistake is not a big deal.  A vote score swing of 2 (+1 instead of -1) and a rep swing of 12 (+10 instead of -2) is not a big deal, especially if you leave a comment and someone else downvotes based on that comment.  Allowing you to change your vote would create potential for abuse across the entire network, which is a much bigger deal.